# Condensing jQuery slidetoggle function

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm new to jQuery and the way it's used so forgive me in advance.

I'm making an FAQ page and I'm using jQuery to toggle divs to open/close on click... My first issue is trying to condense the amount of code being used, as you can see in the code example listed below also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveburns/qLcxquje/)! there is a fair amount of JS and each div has a separate id which is a bit messy.

Many thanks in advance.

```js
$('#logon').click(function()
 {
  $('.logonanswer').slideToggle("fast");
  $('.ecrfanswer').hide(1000);
 });
 $('#ecrf').click(function()
 {
  $('.ecrfanswer').slideToggle("fast");
  $('.logonanswer').hide(1000);
 });
 $('#user').click(function()
 {
  $(".user").slideToggle("fast");
 });
 $('#password').click(function()
 {
  $(".password").slideToggle("fast");
 });
 $('#memorable').click(function()
 {
  $(".memorable").slideToggle("fast");
 });
 $('#disabled').click(function()
 {
  $(".disabled").slideToggle("fast");
 });
 $('#training').click(function()
 {
  $(".training").slideToggle("fast");
 });
 $('#ecrftest').click(function()
 {
  $(".ecrftest").slideToggle("fast");
 });
 $('#dropdown').click(function()
 {
  $(".dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
 });
 $('#check').click(function()
 {
  $(".check").slideToggle("fast");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article style="text-align:left;">
 <h1>Please select your issue</h1>

 <button class="btn btn-b btn-ba icon-key" id="logon">Issues logging in to Syneclin.net</button>
 
 <div class="logonanswer" style="display:none;">
  <p class="expand">
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go" id="user">I have lost my User ID</li>
    <p class="user" style="display:none;">Insert some blurb here about user ID's</p>
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go" id="password">I have lost my Password</li>
    <p class="password" style="display:none;">Insert some blurb here about user ID's</p>
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go" id="memorable">I have lost my Memorable Data</li>
    <p class="memorable" style="display:none;">Insert some blurb here about user ID's</p>
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go" id="disabled">My account has been disabled</li>
    <p class="disabled" style="display:none;">Insert some blurb here about user ID's</p>
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go" id="training">Training??</li>
    <p class="training" style="display:none;">Insert some blurb here about user ID's</p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <button class="btn btn-b btn-ba icon-page" id="ecrf">Issues entering data / accessing eCRF's</button>

 <div class="ecrfanswer" style="display:none;">
  <div class="expand">
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go" id="ecrftest">eCRF Test Page</li>
    <p class="ecrftest" style="display:none;">Insert some blurb here about user ID's</p>
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go" id="dropdown">I can't delete information in a dropdown menu</li>
    <p class="dropdown" style="display:none;">Insert some blurb here about user ID's</p>
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go" id="check">I can't remove a check from a checkbox</li>
    <p class="check" style="display:none;">Insert some blurb here about user ID's</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="footer">
  
 </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qLcxquje/5/

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
    // a list of ids also used as classes
    var listOfIds = ["user", "password", "memorable", 
                     "disabled", "training", "ecrftest", 
                     "dropdown",  "check" ];

    $('#logon').click(function()
    {
        $('.logonanswer').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.ecrfanswer').hide(1000);
    });

    $('#ecrf').click(function()
    {
        $('.ecrfanswer').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.logonanswer').hide(1000);
    });

    // convert JavaScript array to a jQuery array
    var jqueryArr = $.makeArray(listOfIds);
    // map each id to it's corresponding class 
    // and bind the click functionality
    $.map(jqueryArr, function(value, index) {
         $("#" + value).click(function()
         {
            $("." + value).slideToggle("fast");
         });
    });
});
```

Good thing your ids and their corresponding classes match or else this code snippet will not work. Refer to the comments I added on the code for the explanation/functionality. I converted the JavaScript array to a jQuery object so that I can use jQuery's [map](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) functionality.

Here's another answer without using id array ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLcxquje/8/)):

```
// another solution without the id array
$(function(){
    $('#logon').click(function()
    {
        $('.logonanswer').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.ecrfanswer').hide(1000);
    });

    $('#ecrf').click(function()
    {
        $('.ecrfanswer').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.logonanswer').hide(1000);
    });

    // gets the div (the one with expand class) 
    // under the div with class name logonanswer 
    var childDivOfLogonAnswer = $(".logonanswer").children().first();   
    // iterates on all li children only
    $.each(childDivOfLogonAnswer.children('li'), function(index, value) {
        // get the id
        var id = $(value).attr('id');
        // attach click
        $("#" + id).click(function()
        {
            $("." +id).slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });    

    $.each($(".ecrfanswer").children().first().children('li'),
     function(index, value) {
        // get the id
        var id = $(value).attr('id');
        // attach click
        $("#" + id).click(function()
        {
            $("." +id).slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
});
```

Do not forget to change `<p class="expand">` (under `<div class="logonanswer" style="display:none;">`) to `<div class="expand">` for this code snippet to work

Comment: That works perfectly, many thanks for your help, especially with the commenting to explain what the function is doing! :)